# Javascript & PHP :: What to do?

Tags: php, javascript, text-files

I have a string, get by Javascript (the content of a div!);
I want to write this string to PHP, because i want a text file with this content!

How is the best way to do this?

**Edit[1]:** Method Post doesn't works, because i have '<' chars and it erase them (i don't know why)...
Example: I have `#include <stdio.h>` and when i call echo $_REQUEST just show `#include`
...

Comment: Please, Be more specific

Comment: It's not showing the '<' chars because your browser thinks they're tags. Try using `echo htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST);` instead, or use `header('Content-type: text/plain');` before you echo anything. Then you will see that the '<' chars are actually there. If you try writing to a file (without the `htmlspecialchars`), it will work.

Answer (score 1):

For the Javascript part, I suggest using [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It could be triggered, for example, when a button is clicked.

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  url: "process_ajax_div.php",
  data: { divHTML: $('#yourdiv').html() }, 
  success: function(){ alert('done!'); },
  error: function(){ alert('error!'); }
});
```

For the PHP part (file process_ajax_div.php) you can do something like this:

```
<?php
   $divHTML = $_POST['divHTML'];

   // now do whatever you want with $divHTML
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

POST the string to the server, the simplest way is to add the value to a form on the page and submit it, but you could submit the value via AJAX if you like... here is the simple example.

```
<div id="mydiv">Hello World</div>

<form method="post" action="myphppage.php" id="myform">
    <textarea name="mytext" id="mytext"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create File">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("mytext").value = document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML();
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the string text via url to the .php file
that will process it.

There are many ways to accomplish that, one, very simple, could be:

```
var text = "some";
var url = "http://myserver/webapp/file.php?content=" + text;
location.href = url;
```

or with form or with Ajax and so on...

Comment: Don't forget to URL escape the data.